# Arrow Commands in Python Turtle

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics, tkinter-canvas

I have been trying to put turtle in tkinter using the canvas feature. I want to be able to make a turtle etcher sketcher thing so that I can control the turtle with arrow keys. I cannot seem to get it to work and don't understand the error it spits out:

`NameError: name 'Screen' is not defined`

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import turtle

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("750x500")
window.resizable(0,0)

app = tk.Canvas(master = window,
                width = 500,
                height = 500,
                bg = "white")
app.pack()
Screen()
turtle = turtle.RawTurtle(app)
turtle = turtle.Screen()

def k1():
    move.forward(1)

def k2():
    move.left(1)

def k3():
    move.right(1)

def k4():
    move.back(1)

turtle.onkey(k1, "Up")
turtle.onkey(k2, "Left")
turtle.onkey(k3, "Right")
turtle.onkey(k4, "Down")

turtle.listen()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: use `turtle.Screen()` instead of `Screen()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use

```
turtle.Screen()
```

instead of

```
Screen()
```

---

But I see other problems with code. And I would use `tkinter` method `bind()`  to execute function when key is pressed.

```
import tkinter as tk
import turtle

# --- functions ---

def k1(event):
    t.forward(1)

def k2(event):
    t.left(1)

def k3(event):
    t.right(1)

def k4(event):
    t.back(1)

# --- main ---

window = tk.Tk()

window.geometry("750x500")
window.resizable(False, False)

canvas = tk.Canvas(master=window, width=500, height=500, bg="white")
canvas.pack()

t = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)

window.bind("<Up>", k1)
window.bind("<Left>", k2)
window.bind("<Right>", k3)
window.bind("<Down>", k4)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: In the opening to your answer, I wouldn't recommend using `turtle.Screen()` in this situation as it will potentially create a *second* tkinter root window, leading to subtle errors later (like images not working.)  I'd recommend `TurtleScreen()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just as you used `RawTurtle` instead of `Turtle`, when you use turtle *embedded* in a tkinter window, you need to use `TurtleScreen` instead of `Screen`, if you want the methods it provides:

```
import tkinter as tk
from turtle import TurtleScreen, RawTurtle

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("750x500")
window.resizable(0, 0)

canvas = tk.Canvas(master=window, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
turtle = RawTurtle(screen)

def k1():
    turtle.forward(1)

def k2():
    turtle.left(1)

def k3():
    turtle.right(1)

def k4():
    turtle.back(1)

screen.onkey(k1, "Up")
screen.onkey(k2, "Left")
screen.onkey(k3, "Right")
screen.onkey(k4, "Down")

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

Don't use *standalone* turtle's `Screen` in this situation, as it will potentially create a second tkinter root window, leading to subtle errors later (like images not loading.)

Comment: Could you add a description as to why `TurtleScreen()` is better than `turtle.Screen()`. It would serve to improve this answer as it is your answer does not say the "why".

Comment: @Mike-SMT, I included the *why* in my comment on @furas answer which copied the OP's mistake of using `Screen` -- I've copied that explanation into my answer to make it more complete, as you correctly suggest.